# disable dragging in ckeditor

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor, fckeditor, rich-text-editor

I am facing an issue with my ckeditor. I am loading an entire page of HTML into the ckeditor. It's loading and showing fine. I want to let users edit only the data (texts), but not its alignment. But in editor each div is draggable (like the textbox in office word). How can I lock these areas.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider using [Jeditable](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable) instead of ckeditor. That way you can individually allow users to edit each text block.

Comment: Thats great. I will consider that for my next project. But I googled for the above solution, and somebody says put a span around the div with class 'Locked'. But thats not working in all cases. Now I just want to disable draging.

Answer (score 0):

I've used the following JS code before to disable text selection. You might be able to use it to bind to the div/whatever holds the ckeditor instance. Note that this would also prevent the user from being able to select text (for instance to copy/cut/etc).

```
// From http://chris-barr.com/entry/disable_text_selection_with_jquery/
$(function(){
    $.extend($.fn.disableTextSelect = function() {
        return this.each(function(){
            if($.browser.mozilla){//Firefox
                $(this).css('MozUserSelect','none');
            }else if($.browser.msie){//IE
                $(this).bind('selectstart',function(){return false;});
            }else{//Opera, etc.
                $(this).mousedown(function(){return false;});
            }
        });
    });
    $('.noSelect').disableTextSelect();//No text selection on elements with a class of 'noSelect'
});
```

Comment: I dont want to block the text selection. I just want to disable the draging of div or span elements in the content.

Comment: @Arun, I believe the text select will prevent the dragging from taking place as you want but yes, a side effect is that you can't select text any more.

Comment: Ok, it was just an option for you.

Answer (score 0):

Have you added custom styles to the `div` element? In my case, the problem was that I had some styling - especially `overflow: hidden`. Removing the `overflow`, `height` and `min-height` rules helped for me: the handles disappeared.

Note that you can still add the rules where you actually display the content.